# Saving a place on Google Maps account

Tags: google-account, google-maps, geolocation

I want to save a place in Google Maps and put description/notes on it..

When I used Symbian, after clicking on the star to add the place as favorite, I could put name and description in the place, and in my Google Maps account, the places get the name and description I put.

In Android I can't find this feature, I can't write notes in a favorite place. Is this feature deprecated? How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that feature has been replaced by the Check-In feature that Google is trying to promote, so that you use there location based app (Latitude). When you check-in you can add info and reviews.

Google it trying to promote Latitude as a loaction based social app where you can share your location and interact better with your friends and also provide reviews for the selected starred location.